# Is this an accurate/correct example of pre-exercise? If not, what are some examples?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

(After having read Piaget, I'm not sure if this could be considered pre-exercise, or not.)

Pre-exercise through symbolic assimilation could be alternately described as imitating a mode of being in behavior so as to increase the Child's understanding of said role, and to prepare them for such a role when they reach adulthood. It is pre-exercise precisely for this finalistic preparatory nature. An example; a child caring for a doll, like her mother would, is pre-exercise of the maternal instinct. Acting as such in order to assimilate to the role that she doesn't yet fully comprehend on a conceptual level.

Comment: Could you include a concrete (APA) reference of what you read from Piaget?

Comment: I agree with @StevenJeuris' recommendation. I couldn't find a reference for "pre-exercise Piaget" from some simple searching.